# Can I pass "this" to a Q_Slot?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qwidget

I have an application with many windows (QWidgets).
I didn't save a list of open windows, though, so everytime I want to close a window, I have to retrieve it.

Particularly, each of these windows is called here *SubWindow*.
Every SubWindow class contains a layout with a MultiEditor *sEditors, which has a menu with an action that closes the current window.
Every SubWindow is created within the MainWindow.

I have two plans.
1) destroying the SubWindow from within itself, by adding in the SubWindow constructor

```
connect(sEditors, SIGNAL(closeWindow()),
        this, closeWindow()));
```

or

2) destroying the SubWindow from within the MainWindow class, by adding in the SubWindow constructor

```
connect(sEditors, SIGNAL(closeWindow()),
        main, SLOT(closeWindow(this)));
```

About 1), I don't understand how I can close and destroy a QWidget from within itself (*delete this;* didn't seem to work, but I can try again).

About 2) my SLOT(closeWindow(this)) doesn't seem to be triggered, so I am wondering if I can pass "this" as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1) You can use `QObject::deleteLater()`. This will destroy the object in the next event loop cycle, and is specifically create for situations like this

Ad 2) You cannot pass actual arguments as parameters in signal-slot connections.
You can however find out who has emitted the signal by using the `sender()` function in the slot. In your case, that would be the `sEditors` object.

Other options:

3) You can use a `QSignalMapper` to map signals from your editors to the Subwindows.

4) (Using Qt5 / C++11) You can use a lambda connection in your Subwindows:

```
connect(sEditors, SIGNAL(closeWindow()), [this] () {this->closeWindow();});
```

Comment: For some reason (that I don't know), my deleteLater() is not working. I trigger it within my closeWindow() and my QWidget remains -> it doesn't disappear. The QWidget doesn't disappear even if I write close() [or this->close()] or hide() [this->hide()]

Comment: It seems you are closing / deleting / hiding the wrong widget. Verify that `this` points to the correct object in your slot with your debugger

Answer (score 0):

> Can I pass `this` to a Qt slot?

A slot is a non-static method, so it already has access to `this`. The `this` you refer to is the third argument to `QObject::connect`. In Qt 4 syntax, you're free to omit the third argument - it defaults to `this`. In Qt 5 syntax, you must be explicit about it, though.

> I don't understand how I can close and destroy a QWidget from within itself

To delete any `QObject` from within itself, use `QObject::deleteLater()`. Recall that a `QWidget` is-a `QObject` in terms of [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

> my SLOT(closeWindow(this)) doesn't seem to be triggered

There's no such slot (give us a link to its documentation: you can't), and your slot signature is also invalid because the only things within the parentheses in the slot signature  can be types, and `this` is not a type: `SLOT(slotName(TYPE_LIST_HERE))`, e.g. `SLOT(mySlot(int,QString))`.

To close a widget, use its `close()` slot:

```
connect(sEditors, SIGNAL(closeWindow()), this, SLOT(close());
```

Yet, by using Qt 4 `connect` syntax, you're leaving coding mistakes to be detected at runtime - and then if you don't pay attention to the debug output at runtime, you'll miss it. It's thus much better to use the new (Qt 5) `connect` syntax, and let the compiler detect errors for you:

```
connect(sEditors, &MultiEditor::closeWindow, this, &QWidget::close);
```

Alas, there's no need to tightly couple the object that sends `closeWindow` to `SubWindow` - at least not within the `SubWindow::SubWindow()`. Instead, you can connect at the place where you create the editor.

To delete a widget when it gets closed, simply set the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute on it and let Qt do it for you. No need to explicitly call `deleteLater` etc.

You might factor all of it into a factory method:

```
template <class T> T* SubWindow::makeEditor() {
  auto sub = new T{this};
  sub->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
  connect(sEditor, &MultiEditor::closeWindow, sub, &QWidget::close);
  return sub;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(/*...*/) : /*...*/ {
  makeEditor<EditorType1>();
  makeEditor<EditorType2>();
  /*...*/
}
```

Comment: The Qt5 syntax is very useful, thanks! For some reason (that I don't know), my deleteLater() is not working. I trigger it within my closeWindow() function and my QWidget remains -> it doesn't disappear. The QWidget doesn't disappear even if I write close() [or this->close()] or hide() [this->hide()], nor if I write connect(sEditors, &MultiEditor::closeWindow, this, &QWidget::close);